# Wanting to format a string so it splits into two strings, I cant quite get the format right

Tags: c#, split

My main input is from a string seperated by a commar, but I am having a hard time to see how to split the string so it send the values to the correct array.

```
Input format = "39.6, 3.068"

for (int i = 0; i < wholeAdresse.Length; i++)
{
        //string phrase = wholeAdresse[index];
        string[] output = wholeAdresse[i].Split(',');

        foreach (var myOutput in output )
        {
         //System.Console.WriteLine($"<{myOutput }>");
         Alist.Add(myOutput [0]);   ---->Hoped for output "39.6"
         Blist.Add(myOutput [1]);   ---->Hoped for output "3.068" 
        }
}
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: What type is `wholeAdresse`?

Comment: Addition to @SpencerBench, what is value in `wholeAdresse`?

Comment: What is a "wholeAdresse" in this scenario? Becuase all I see here is that you want values from "input format" but single String.Split will do.

Comment: For now I counted them as strings and must split only at the comma
 (it needs the "." for later - converted back into floats)

Comment: Have you tried ... `Alist.Add(myOutput);` ... Currently, `Alist.Add(myOutput [0]);` ... is attempting to add a single CHARACTER into `Alist`.

Answer (score 1):

As the data items are on lines, it seems very likely that they are associated with each other, for example they could be latitude-longitude pairs. In that case, it would make sense to create a class to represent the data from one line so that all the individual parts can be conveniently kept together instead of you trying to remember which array is for what.

Perhaps something like this console app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        public class LatLon
        {
            public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
            public decimal Longitude { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string[] wholeAdresse = new string[] { "39.6, 3.068", "40.12, 2.998" };

            List<LatLon> listA = new List<LatLon>();

            for (int i = 0; i < wholeAdresse.Length; i++)
            {
                string[] output = wholeAdresse[i].Split(',');

                listA.Add(new LatLon()
                {
                    Latitude = decimal.Parse(output[0].Trim()),
                    Longitude = decimal.Parse(output[1].Trim())
                });
            }

            foreach (var ll in listA)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Lat: " + ll.Latitude + " Lon: " + ll.Longitude);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Lat: 39.6 Lon: 3.068
Lat: 40.12 Lon: 2.998
```

Notice how it is easy to use `ll.Latitude` and `ll.Longitude`: you'll know what they are.

Comment: Nice! and yes your correct! ;p good spotting